# How to use PHP-FPM with aliased directories

Tags: php, apache, fastcgi, fpm

I am experimenting with upgrading my Centos 7 server from **PHP5 to PHP7**, and it appears that it's also advised to use the fpm approach as well (which I'm new to).

On my test server, I've installed **PHP7.3** no problem, and PHP-FPM. And adding the line

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/my_doc_root/$1
```

Works.... sort of.

The problem is that, for reasons historical and beyond my control, I have various paths aliased onto /, but which are not within the document root. i.e

```
Alias /myURL /some/different/path
```

Obviously the problem is that the `ProxyPassMatch` command above will redirect "myURL/fish.php" to a non-existent file ("my_doc_root/fish.php") which gives an error.

Is there a simple solution to this problem? e.g. something I can put in the `<Directory>` entries for the document root and for `some/different/path`.  Alternatively, is there a way I can update the `/etc/https/conf.d/php.conf` **(from PHP5) to run PHP7** in the old-style way? I don't think I can as there was no libphp file in the **php73** packages.

Obviously there are solutions (write separate `ProxyPassMatch` directives for every URL not in the document root or reorganize the entire filesystem in a more intelligent way), but I'd rather avoid these if I can; indeed, the latter I simply can't do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting your aliases before the `ProxyPassMatch` directive, since if it finds that first then the alias will be ignored.

```
Alias /myURL /some/different/path
<Directory "/some/different/path/">
    AllowOverride All
    require ip 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

> UPDATE Possibly this will help you https://serverfault.com/questions/629099/apache-2-4-php-fpm-mod-proxy-fcgi-alias

Comment: Hmm, no effect. Tried moving my `ProxyPassMatch` to the end, (and adding the require ip which is not in my <directory> at the moment) but I still get the file not found error. I guess the `ProxyPassMatch` is still trying to rewrite to the document root, not the actual dir it's in.

Comment: Perfect - thanks.
For posterity, it was literally adding:
`<FilesMatch \.php$>  SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"  </FilesMatch>`
To the beginning of the `VirtualHost` tag

Comment: glad you're up and running!